# Is it possible to rejoin a dungeon in progress?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I was running Fractals of the Mists with a pickup group recently, and part of the way through the second fractal, one of the party members was somehow ejected from the dungeon. His portrait changed to a black silhouette and in party chat he said that he was outside the entrance and couldn't find a way to get back in. Even after we completed the second fractal, the party member said that he couldn't find a way to rejoin the group.

**Is it possible for a party member to rejoin an instance of a dungeon that's already underway? Is there any difference between Fractals of the Mists and other dungeons in this regard?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rejoin your party in any of the dungeons *except* the Fractals of the Mists.  You do so simply by re-entering the game; assuming you're still in the party, you should be placed outside the dungeon and be given the option to join your party inside.

Fractals of the Mists are a bit different; you can't rejoin if you leave or are disconnected. This has to do with how they designed the Fractals, with the level restrictions being one of the major causes.

ArenaNet is currently working on correcting this known and frustrating issue with a patch that they've planned to deliver around the end of January.  See [this blog post](https://www.guildwars2.com/en/news/fractals-of-the-mists-dungeon-improvements/) for more details.

Comment: I would also like to note that you can also swap members in other dungeons as well, so if you lose a member, you can bring someone else in.  Fractals are designed to only be run with the people you bring in, though; that's part of the challenge.  You keep going as far as you can until either your party disbands or your armor is too far degraded to continue.

Comment: As an update: you can rejoin your party in Fractals of the Mists now.